# Tagfiles (.tag) in JAR (Java App) not picked up in RAD 7

Tags: jar, jsp-tags, rad, tagfile

I am using Websphere 6.1.0.23 and RAD7.  I have a Java App (SearchJava) which has a tagfile cluster.tag under src/META-INF/tags.  I also have search.tld under src/META-INF/tld which has

```
    <taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" 
  version="2.0"> 
    <tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
    <short-name></short-name>
    <uri>http://x.y.z/search/tags</uri>
    <tag-file>
        <name>cluster</name>
        <path>/META-INF/tags/cluster.tag</path>
     </tag-file>
</taglib>
```

I have a web app (SearchWeb) which has a dependency on my java app (configured as a Web Library using J2EE Module Dependencies).  When I start my server in RAD, it can find the tld, but it can't seem to find the tag file.  However when I deploy to a standalone Websphere 6.1 instance (i.e. without RAD) it works.  This is the error I'm seeing.

```
[04/05/11 11:20:54:359 IST] 00000016 WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: SearchWeb.
[04/05/11 11:20:54:703 IST] 00000016 jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [search.tld]: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /META-INF/tags/cluster.tag
[04/05/11 11:20:54:703 IST] 00000016 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadLooseLibTagFiles jsp error failed to parse loose library tld . location = [C:\CCRC\common_apps\SearchJava\bin/META-INF/tld]
                                 com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /META-INF/tags/cluster.tag
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser.parseTLD(TldParser.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.loadLooseLibTagFiles(TagLibraryCache.java:554)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.loadLooseLibTagFiles(TagLibraryCache.java:589)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.loadLooseLibTagFiles(TagLibraryCache.java:589)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache.<init>(TagLibraryCache.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.<init>(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.ws.WASJSPExtensionProcessor.<init>(WASJSPExtensionProcessor.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.ws.WASJSPExtensionFactory.createProcessor(WASJSPExtensionFactory.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionFactory.createExtensionProcessor(AbstractJSPExtensionFactory.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeExtensionProcessors(WebApp.java:1191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:345)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:292)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:671)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:624)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1165)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:832)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:921)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2124)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
```

Does anybody know how to get this to work?  Is there something I can configure in RAD?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error this week, I think the problem is because RAD uses the workspace resouces, you could change the configuration of the server to use the server resource instead of the workspace, then it works fine.

Double Click in the Server, in **Server View** in the section 
**Publishing settings for WebSphere Application Server** select **Run server with resources on Server**